# Clojure priority-map with finite size

Tags: clojure

I wanted to extend Clojure [priority-map](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map) to support priority-map with finite capacity. Once priority-map is initialized with a size, it will drop additional items during assoc based on priority if current count is equal to the capacity of the map.

I am thinking of implementing this using deftype and changing the implementation of assoc. But I am not sure whether this is the best way or whether it is possible to only override assoc and into operations.

Really appriciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Zach Tellman's [potemkin](https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin) library, specifically its `def-map-type` macro, to define a custom map type holding a priority map inside it. You'd only have to provide explicit implementations for `get`, `assoc`, `dissoc` and `keys` -- all the other Clojure and Java methods would be implemented for you automatically. Given your use case, `get`, `dissoc` and `keys` could pretty much delegate to the internal priority map, while `assoc` would implement the dropping logic.

You might also want to have a look at [core.cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache), which uses priority maps to implement its cache types.